# read data from text file in batch. store in two temporary variables when looping

Tags: arrays, batch-file, winscp

Trying to read username and password from text file, each username and password separated on new line in txt file.
Not able to iterate over the array and get first element and second element from array and assign to `varUser` and `varPass`, then third and fourth and so on. These two temporary variables will be used as parameter for winScp console for login sftp server. The script.txt file has command to connect that takes `varUser` and `varPass` as parameter from batch file.

```
rem 1. reading text file and filling in array

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    call echo i=%%i%%
    call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
    call set lastIndex=%%i%%
)

rem 2. reading array values from filled array and store in temp varUser and varPass

set /a i=0
set /a j=1
for /L %%i in (1,2,%lastIndex%) do (
    call echo %%array[%%i]%%
    set varUser=%%array[%%i]%%
    set varPass=%%array[%%j]%%
    winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put %varUser%,%varPass%
    set /a j+=1
)
```

Comment: If you set **and use** an environment variable in a (code block) you need [DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Also your question is unclear, where do you fill the array? There is no for variable `%%j` and `%j%` is set and incremented but never used.

Comment: i am filling the array in fist loop by reading the txt file and second loop trying to iterate the previously stored value and put it in temp variable varUser and varPass, i am trying to do something like  varUser=a[i] and varPass=a[i+1] in the second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your `file.txt` is constructed as:

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
user3 password3
...
```

This does exactly what you attempted in 2 loops (besides attempting to set an array)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
    set varUser=%%a
    set varPass=%%b
    echo user=!varUser! password=!varPass!
    winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put !varUser!,!varPass!
)
```

That is pretty unneeded though as you can simply use the metavariables as is to run the commands.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
    winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put %%a,%%b
)
```

If you really want to set an array and use it like you did, for an unknown reason:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set varUser[!cnt!]=%%a
    set varPass[!cnt!]=%%b
)

for /l %%i in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    echo user=!varUser[%%i]! password=!varPass[%%i]!
)
```

If on the other hand your `file.txt` is in complete list form, like:

```
user1
password1
user2
password2
user3
password3
...
```

Then this is probably what you wanted to get to `:)`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set array[!cnt!]=%%a
)

set handler=0
for /l %%i in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    set /a handler+=1
    call set varUser=%%array[!handler!]%%
    set /a handler+=1
    call set varPass=%%array[!handler!]%%
    echo user=!varUser! password=!varPass!
    winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put !varUser!,!varPass!
    if "!handler!"=="!cnt!" goto :eof
)
```

This last example is what you seem to want, based on your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

just to give an alternative without an array and without `for`:

```
@echo off
<file.txt call :read
goto :eof

:read
  set "user="
  set "pass="
  set /p user=
  set /p pass=
  if "%user%%pass%"=="" goto :eof
  echo %user%, %pass%
goto :read
```

Assuming following (suboptimal) format for `file.txt`:

```
user1
password1
user2
password2
user3
password3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "varUser="

for /f "delims=" %%A in (file.txt) do (
    if defined varUser (
        call winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put %%varUser%%,%%A
        set "varUser="
    ) else set "varUser=%%A"
)
```

1st loop cycle to set the value of `varUser` and the 2nd loop cycle to execute `winscp`. It will keeping looping until reaches end of file. Perhaps easier than what you tried with a variable name sequence.

This will work with reading a file such as:

> ```
> jack
> boy
> jill
> girl!
> ```

If you put the user and the password on the same line for each user, then you could use:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in (file2.txt) do (
    winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put %%A,%%B
)
```

This will work with reading a file such as:

> ```
> jack boy
> jill girl!
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just another variant, using

- `findstr /n` to read the file and number the lines
- a `for /l` with step 2 to process the Array

With a file `UserPass.txt`:

```
user1
password1
user2
password2
user3
password3
```

This batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\10\SO_56083497.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /N "." ^<".\UserPass.txt"'
    ) do Set "Array[%%i]=%%j"&Set n=%%i

for /l %%i in (1,2,%n%) do (
    Set /a j=%%i+1
    Call Set "varPass=%%Array[!j!]%%"
    echo winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put !Array[%%i]!,!varPass!
)
```

yields this output (remove the `echo` in front of `winscp`)

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\10\SO_56083497.cmd
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put user1,password1
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put user2,password2
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter put user3,password3
```